# Android studio Endpoints generating error in library

Tags: android, android-studio, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, android-studio-3.0

I have an appengine module in my project with a few different endpoints and when I go to try to `Make project` or `Build APK` Android studio generates the endpoint libraries but recently the libraries are getting generated with errors

It creates this method for each endpoint

```
@Override
public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) {
  return (Builder) super.setBatchPath(batchPath);
}
```

the error says `Error:(418, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

The library generation was working fine a while ago when I first built the backend and the only thing that changed was I updated Android Studio 3.0 to the latest beta.

my gradle versions are all up to date

`classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'`

`classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'`

I am kind of dead in the water right now since my app uses the libraries and wont build, does anyone know how I can fix this problem? Is it an Android Studio problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Google API client libraries were updated yesterday. You have to update all of your dependencies with the group `com.google.api-client` to `1.23.0`.